# Supervisord - running a python script that needs to interact with the terminal

Tags: python, supervisord

I have a python script, which takes a keyboard entry and enters it into a csv file. There will be a number of Raspberries which perform the same task and I want to look at a management process, to make sure that the Python script is still running.

I was looking at Supervisord, which starts my script and I can monitor the script remotely - however when supervisord starts the python script, it stops it interacting with the terminal - so any keyboard entries aren't picked up by the script. Is there any way to make the python code start but interact with the commandline?

PS This is the first bit of coding, so definitely a Noob!

---

Supervisord.conf:

---

```
; Sample supervisor config file.
;
; For more information on the config file, please see:
; http://supervisord.org/configuration.html
;
; Notes:
;  - Shell expansion ("~" or "$HOME") is not supported.  Environment
;    variables can be expanded using this syntax: "%(ENV_HOME)s".
;  - Comments must have a leading space: "a=b ;comment" not "a=b;comment".

[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0700                 ; socket file mode (default 0700)
;chown=nobody:nogroup       ; socket file uid:gid owner
;username=user              ; (default is no username (open server))
;password=123               ; (default is no password (open server))

[inet_http_server]         ; inet (TCP) server disabled by default
port=*:9001        ; (ip_address:port specifier, *:port for all iface)
username=user              ; (default is no username (open server))
password=pswd               ; (default is no password (open server))

[supervisord]
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB        ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10           ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=info                ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trace)
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=false               ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                  ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                 ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)
;umask=022                   ; (process file creation umask;default 022)
user=pi                 ; (default is current user, required if root)
;identifier=supervisor       ; (supervisord identifier, default is 'supervisor')
;directory=/tmp              ; (default is not to cd during start)
;nocleanup=true              ; (don't clean up tempfiles at start;default false)
;childlogdir=/tmp            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)
;environment=KEY="value"     ; (key value pairs to add to environment)
;strip_ansi=false            ; (strip ansi escape codes in logs; def. false)

; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket
;serverurl=http://10.55.0.102:9001 ; use an http:// url to specify an inet socket
username=user             ; should be same as http_username if set
password=pswd                ; should be same as http_password if set
;prompt=mysupervisor         ; cmd line prompt (default "supervisor")
;history_file=~/.sc_history  ; use readline history if available


[program:GIST]
command=/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Main.py -DFOREGROUND
;command=/home/pi/Main.py
numprocs=1
autostart=true
startsecs=1
startretries=3
autorestart=unexpected
exitcodes=0,2
stopsignal=QUIT
user=User

; The below sample eventlistener section shows all possible
; eventlistener subsection values, create one or more 'real'
; eventlistener: sections to be able to handle event notifications
; sent by supervisor.



; The below sample group section shows all possible group values,
; create one or more 'real' group: sections to create "heterogeneous"
; process groups.

;[group:thegroupname]
;programs=progname1,progname2  ; each refers to 'x' in [program:x] definitions
;priority=999                  ; the relative start priority (default 999)

; The [include] section can just contain the "files" setting.  This
; setting can list multiple files (separated by whitespace or
; newlines).  It can also contain wildcards.  The filenames are
; interpreted as relative to this file.  Included files *cannot*
; include files themselves.

;[include]
;files = relative/directory/*.ini
```

---

Python Script:

---

```
import sys, select, datetime, select, fcntl, socket, struct, time, os

#t = datetime.datetime.now()
#timenow = time.mktime(t.timetuple())

def getmac(interface):
        try:
                mac = open('/sys/class/net/'+interface+'/address').readline()
        except:
                mac = "00:00:00:00:00:00"
        return mac[0:17]
myMAC = getmac("wlan0")

def get_ip_addr(ifname):
        try:
                s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
                return socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(
                        s.fileno(),
                        0x8915,  # SIOCGIFADDR
                        struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15])
                    )[20:24])
        except:
                ()

print get_ip_addr('wlan0')
print myMAC


IPAddr = get_ip_addr('wlan0')

while True:
        if os.path.lexists('/home/pi/GistLog.csv'):

                i, o, e, = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 3600)
                if (i):
                        id = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
                        if id == "exit":
                                        break
                        t = datetime.datetime.now()
                        timenow = time.mktime(t.timetuple())

                        with open("/home/pi/GistLog.csv", "a") as Log:
                                Log.write (id + "," +str(timenow)+ "," + str(myMAC) + "," + str(IPAddr) + "," + "\n")

                        print"Scan Successful"
                        print t

                else:
                        print"Scan Error"
        else:
                i, o, e, = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 3600)
                if (i):
                        id = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
                        if id == "exit":
                                break
                        t = datetime.datetime.now()
                        timenow = time.mktime(t.timetuple())

                        with open("/home/pi/GistLog.csv", "a") as Log:
                                Log.write ("id,rfid,timestamp,MAC,IPAddr,\n" + id + "," +str(timenow)+ "," + str(myMAC) + "," + str(IPAddr) + "," + "\n")
                else:
                        print"Scan Error"
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work it out - I figured out the supervisorctl fg command, which brought the process to the foreground and let me interact with it.

I also managed to get this to autostart from the /etc/profile so it launches the supervisord process, sleeps 5, then launches the supervisorctl fb command.

Chris